# Uploading image to server (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, upload

I try to send image as byte[] to server.
When I sent it from POST-MAN, like html will send files, it works.

But when I try to send from Objective C code, it sents different array of bytes:

```
+ (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage*)photo withCompletionBlock:(responceBlock)block
{
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
 NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 6);
 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[UserDefaultsHelper getToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN"];
 AFHTTPRequestOperation* op = [manager POST:@"http://localhost:8080/image/save"
 parameters:@{}
 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
 [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"ParamFiles" fileName:@"photo2131231.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {
 NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
 NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];
 [op start];
}
```

**Answer:** Sorry for stupid question. Problem, that on server I handle just binary image. Objective C code send me multipart files, so it contains binary image with filename, mimetype and other fields. I converted everything to bytes and tried to save this like image. Of course server can't do that.

Comment: So, what's the problem? The data array is different? Or you are facing any error?

Comment: When I send from IOS, it send different bytes with different length, so at server it cannot convert to BufferedImage (java)

Comment: Do you get your image when using POST-MAN?

Comment: yes, from POST-MAN  it works

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
+ (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage*)photo withCompletionBlock:(responceBlock)block
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 6);
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[UserDefaultsHelper getToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN"];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [manager.requestSerializer
                                     multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                     URLString:@"http://localhost:8080/image/save"
                                     parameters:nil
                                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                     {
                                         UIImage *image = [page.imageVersionObject imageForVersion:page.imageVersionObject.selectedVersion];
                                         if (image) {

                                             [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, (CGFloat)0.85)
                                                                         name:@"file"
                                                                     fileName:@"fileName.jpg"
                                                                     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                         }
                                     }
                                     error:nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //SUCCESS HERE!!!

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //FAILURE HERE
    }];

    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];



}
```

Do not forget to use your filename and name.... I have used mine for testing

Comment: I feel you have to check your API service that is accepting the image

Comment: Seems you have a config mismatch... check required headers, accepted request formats